# How to use variables in the nth selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I use a variable in the nth-selector?

```
var columnCount = 6;

$('td:nth-child(', columnCount ,')')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenation with **'+'** operator

```
$('td:nth-child('+ columnCount +')')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `+` operator for concatenation of strings.

```
$('td:nth-child(' + columnCount  + ')')
//                ^              ^
```

You can also use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index) or [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get1)

```
$('td').children().eq(columnCount - 1) // Indexing starts with 0
```

OR

```
$('td').children().get(columnCount)
```